# Complex eigenvectors for symmetric matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, eigenvector

I have the following code snippet, trying to compute the eigen-decomposition of a real symmetric matrix

```
K = 3;
n = 10;

Z = rand(n,K);
B = rand(K,K);
B = 0.5*(B+B') + 3*eye(K);
W = Z*B*Z';
if issymmetric(W) && isreal(W)
    [U,D] = eig(W)
end
```

This unfortunately seems to produce genuinely complex eigenvectors on MATLAB R2013a. I used to think that `eig` should keep everything real for real symmetric matrices. Anyone has any idea why this happens?

PS. Changing to n = 6, for example, outputs something real.

Comment: real symmetric matrices can have complex eigenvectors. Even if by hand you generate real ones you can always get complex ones by taking linear combinations within the same eigenspace. 

Just consider this super simple example: can the identity matrix have complex eigenvectors? 

Real symmetric matrices always have real eigen*values*

Comment: @Ben, I understand that, but the idea is that you can get a fully real eigen-decomposition of real symmetric matrices, by keeping all the algebra in the reals. There exists a complete set of real eigenvectors, and I was hoping that matlab can output that.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/309237

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB `eig` usually returns real eigenvectors when the matrix is real and symmetric. Rounding errors can make `Z*B*Z'` slightly unsymmetric. I don't know how `issymmetric` is implemented (it's a built-in function), but maybe `eig` doesn't use the same criterion to determine if a matrix is real and symmetric than `issymmetric`.

A simple way to enforce that the matrix is numerically symmetric is doing `(W+W')./2`. So `eig((W+W')./2)` should return real values and vectors.